# Connect Django with Oracle12C

Tags: django, oracle12c

I have successfully connected to the TESTDB using python program and JDBC and using the same credentials. Now, i want to connect to Django but getting error saying that "ORA-01017: Invalid Username/password; logon denied.

[python manage.py runserver error s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GqQb.png)

[django project settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjbOD.png)

[oracle12c variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAnl1.png)

[listener.ora file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTu1Z.png)

[tnsnames.ora file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqpEF.png)

[connected using python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcO6W.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience goes, an Oracle username must not contain hash signs.